# How to preserve expression ${USER} when shell script creates file where expression vs expression output is desired

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openvpn

Here's my dilemma, in a shell script I use to install or configure OpenVPN and/or just the client config files, I've expanded the script to include the installation of Google Authenticator.

The script creates the `pam.d` file for this add on using `echo`...

```
echo "auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/${USER} user=openvpn account required  pam_permit.so">> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

After all is installed, and the file is created, the pam.d file above of course is created with the user instead of the expression as shown below

```
echo "auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/root user=openvpn account required pam_permit.so">> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

Is there a way to preserve the expression as `${USER}` within the file?

It would solve this post installation edit of changing `secret=/etc/google-auth/root` back to `secret=/etc/google-auth/${USER}`

Comment: [*Difference between single and double quotes in Bash*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753).

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

As Kamil's comment notes, if you want to include the literal text ${USER}, you could use apostrophes instead of quotation marks.

```
echo "auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/${USER} user=openvpn account required  pam_permit.so">> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

will cause the shell to expand ${USER}, which could be set to root.  (If that's not desired, you might want to try preserving that variable with sudo's env_reset ability, or just set the desired value to a custom variable that sudo won't tend to overwrite.)

Actually, you get the same effect without the quotation marks.

```
echo auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/${USER} user=openvpn account required  pam_permit.so>> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

Another option, though, is to use apostrophes instead of where you had quotation marks, as follows:

```
echo 'auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/${USER} user=openvpn account required  pam_permit.so'>> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

Another option is to just escape the dollar sign.

```
echo auth requisite /lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/google-auth/\${USER} user=openvpn account required pam_permit.so>> /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

That backslash before the dollar sign tells the shell to just treat the dollar sign as a regular character, not as the start of a variable name.

Comment: Thanks TOOGAM!! that worked....I ended up using the substitute of apostrophes vs. quotation marks....

Comment: "you get the same effect without the quotation marks" – With `echo` it may work in many cases but it's a *very bad practice in general*. What if there's `|` in a string one wants to echo? or a forkbomb? or `;rm -rf ~/*;`? You can't expect users *who need help with their quotes* to spot such a flaw. Even if they don't do any permanent damage, they will be confused by sudden `command not found` or another behavior they don't expect. I'd like to upvote the answer but I won't unless it's improved.

Comment: I currently plan to leave my answer as is, because it directly addresses the question being asked (where the echo'ed text looks rather specific).  However, I acknowledge the security concerns that @KamilMaciorowski made, and especially appreciate the sentence after Kamil's question mark.  When dealing with unknown or otherwise-untrustable input, such security concerns are well worth the effort, but for this particular case, I don't deem such possible concern as worth making the answer substantially longer. Then again, I don't tend to blindly paste commands or reference unknown variables.